# Spark: out of memory when broadcasting objects

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory

I tried to broadcast a not-so-large map (~ 70 MB when saved to HDFS as text file), and I got out of memory errors. I tried to increase the driver memory to 11G and executor memory to 11G, and still got the same error. The memory.fraction is set to 0.3, and there's not many data (less than 1G) cached either.

When the map is only around 2 MB, there's no problem. I wonder if there is a size limit when broadcasting objects. How can I solve this problem using the bigger map? Thank you!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.resize(IdentityHashMap.java:469)
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:445)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$SearchState.enqueue(SizeEstimator.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitArray(SizeEstimator.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitSingleObject(SizeEstimator.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.org$apache$spark$util$SizeEstimator$$estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTracker$class.takeSample(SizeTracker.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTracker$class.afterUpdate(SizeTracker.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTrackingVector.$plus$eq(SizeTrackingVector.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:648)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:1006)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1327)
```

**Edit:**
Add more information according to the comments:

- I use spark-submit to submit the compiled jar file in client mode. Spark 1.5.0
- spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 600
- set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "256m")
- set("spark.speculation", "true")
- set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.3")
- set("spark.driver.memory", "15G")
- set("spark.executor.memory", "11G")
- I tried set("spar.sql.tungsten.enabled", "false") and it doesn't help.
- The master machine has 60G memory. Around 30G is used for Spark/Yarn. I'm not sure how much heap size is for my job, but there's not much other process going on at the same time. Especially the map is only around 70MB.

Some code related to the broadcasting:

```
val mappingAllLocal: Map[String, Int] = mappingAll.rdd.map(r => (r.getAs[String](0), r.getAs[Int](1))).collectAsMap().toMap
// I can use the above mappingAll to HDFS, and it's around 70MB
val mappingAllBrd = sc.broadcast(mappingAllLocal) // <-- this is where the out of memory happens
```

Comment: How much are heap size and other parameters you might have set? Can you please explain a bit more. BTW how you're submitting your job? Also a bit of code where you're getting the problem?

Comment: @ChikuMiku Thanks! I just edited my question with more information.

Comment: Are you submitting on yarn? if yes then ho many DN you have and what is your container's maximum size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `set("spark.driver.memory", "15G")` has no effect on client mode. You have to use the command line parameter `--conf="spark.driver.memory=15G"` when submitting the application to increase the driver's heap size.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! How do you find out that set("spark.driver.memory", "15G") has no effect on client mode ? Are there any other settings that has no effect on client mode? Thanks!

Comment: It's mentioned in [Spark's documents](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can try increase the JVM heap size :

```
-Xmx2g : max size of 2Go
-Xms2g : initial size of 2Go (default size is 256mo)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't try this solution. I first tried Dikei's solution since it seems more native to Spark.