# PySparkProcessor: how to configure spark.driver.memory in AWS Sagemaker ProcessingStep

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, amazon-sagemaker

I am using [PySparkProcessor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.spark.processing.PySparkProcessor) as one of my processing steps in Sagemaker Pipeline to process the data.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()
with open("unique-guids.json") as f:
    guids = json.load(f)
guids_bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(guids)
```

I am broadcasting a file (*unique-guids.json*) of around 200KB, but I see the following error.

```
2021-11-02T11:55:41.314-04:00   21/11/02 15:55:40 WARN memory.MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache broadcast_12 in memory! (computed 1050.9 MB so far)
2021-11-02T11:55:41.314-04:00   21/11/02 15:55:40 WARN storage.BlockManager: Persisting block broadcast_12 to disk instead.
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   [/var/log/yarn/userlogs/application_1635868431764_0001/container_1635868431764_0001_01_000002/stderr] 21/11/02 15:55:36 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 1343.0#
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   # java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   # -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   # Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 937"...
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   11-02 15:56 smspark-submit ERROR spark-submit command failed with exit code -9: Command 'spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /opt/ml/processing/input/code/xxx.py keycite_uri yyy json_keycite_uri zzz' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>.
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smspark/job.py", line 149, in run subprocess.run(spark_submit_cmd, check=True, shell=True) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /opt/ml/processing/input/code/filter_keycites.py keycite_uri yyy json_keycite_uri zzz' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>.
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   Command 'spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /opt/ml/processing/input/code/filter_keycites.py keycite_uri xxx json_keycite_uri yyy' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>.
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smspark/job.py", line 149, in run subprocess.run(spark_submit_cmd, check=True, shell=True) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /opt/ml/processing/input/code/xx.py keycite_uri zzz json_keycite_uri yyy' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>.
2021-11-02T11:56:08.323-04:00   11-02 15:56 smspark-submit INFO exiting with code -9: Algorithm Error: (caused by CalledProcessError): spark failed with a non-zero exit code: Command 'spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /opt/ml/processing/input/code/xxx.py keycite_uri yyy json_keycite_uri zzz' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>.
```

I guess the issue is related to the *spark.driver.memory* so I tried to override the default **2g** using the following approach but no luck.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").config("spark.driver.memory", "4g").getOrCreate()
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38644726/1545855) answer, I need to use the command line option to configure *driver.memory*. However, in my case, the [ProcesingStep](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html?highlight=ProcessingStep#sagemaker.workflow.steps.ProcessingStep) is launching the spark job, so I don't see any option to pass *driver.memory*. According to the [docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html?highlight=PySparkProcessor#sagemaker.spark.processing.PySparkProcessor.get_run_args) it looks like *RunArgs* object is the option to pass configuration but [ProcessingStep](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html?highlight=ProcessingStep#sagemaker.workflow.steps.ProcessingStep) can't take *RunArgs* or configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out the issue here. When I call [get_run_args()](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.spark.processing.PySparkProcessor.get_run_args), it takes the configuration and uploads it into s3 (*~/input/conf/configuration.json*) but it returns standard *inputs*, *outputs*, *arguments*. This  magic happens inside a private method [_extend_processing_args()](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/7268e82d45b522424891ddd8267ad00ef0cffd23/src/sagemaker/spark/processing.py#L779).

```
    spark_processor = PySparkProcessor(.....)
    configuration=[
        {
            "Classification": "spark-defaults",
            "Properties": {
                "spark.driver.memory": "4g"
            },
        }
    ]
    run_args = spark_processor.get_run_args(submit_app, inputs, outputs, arguments, configuration)
    spark_step = ProcessingStep(
        name=step_name,
        processor=spark_processor,
        code=run_args.code,
        inputs=run_args.inputs,
        outputs=run_args.outputs,
        job_arguments=run_args.arguments
    )
```